# Symfony 4 : Set trusted proxy on Heroku

Tags: symfony, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a secure Symfony 4 application on Heroku.

Since Symfony 4, the front changed. The old Heroku documentation explained how to set the trusted proxies to accept the Heroku load balancer, but since Symfony 4, the method has been changed.

How do you configure your `public/index.php` to accept Heroku Proxies with Symfony 4?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

Just after the line :

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
```

Add :

```
Request::setTrustedProxies([$request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR')], Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL ^ Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST);
```

Comment: Hey athnk  you for ypour response, could explain "Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL ^ Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST" uses and does it work if why dont specifies heards...